# Change an image using the value typed into a textbox

Tags: asp.net, getelementbyid, src

New to Javascript and would appreciate some help with the following, be gentle with me.

I would like to change an image depending on the value typed into a textbox.

My script is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


script type="text/javascript">
function ParImg(Change) {
    var ParImg = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value;
    alert(ParImg);
    Img1.src = Change + ".jpg";
   }
</script>

<img id="Img1" src='apicture.jpg' alt="Random Image" />
```

The alert is showing whatever is typed into the text box but the image is not changing from the default.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong or even can this be done at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getElementById to get the image as well

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<script type="text/javascript">
function ParImg(Change) {
    var ParImg = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value;
    alert(ParImg);
    var Img1 = document.getElementById("Img1");
    Img1.src = Change + ".jpg";
   }
</script>

<img id="Img1" src='apicture.jpg' alt="Random Image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need

`Img1 = document.getElementById("Img1");`

you should be getting some error for the `Img1.src` line as there is no Img1 being declared beforehand

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still does not work and I am not getting an error for the Img1.src line.

Comment: update your question with your code and is the path that you are entering into the textbox lead to an actual image

Comment: I tried all three suggested here so far but the code I used for yours is as follows:

Comment: Sorry about the truncated comment - still trying to get use to things here.  The text being entered into the text box with the addition of .jpg does lead to an actual image.  My code with your suggested addition           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

script type="text/javascript">
function ParImg(Change) {
    var ParImg = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value;
    alert(ParImg);
  Img1 = document.getElementById("Img1");
   Img1.src = Change + ".jpg";
   }
</script>

<img id="Img1" src='apicture.jpg' alt="Random Image" />

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't know what Img1 is.  Try

```
document.getElementById("Img1").src = Change_".jpg";
```